# Styles for colors, emphasis, underline in ALV

Tags: colors, abap, styling, alv

We are trying to manipulate the alv grid class to get result like in Sap Agenda (SSC1 tcode) i.e. to merge columns and rows.

We found that the class `cl_calendar_control_schedule` with the method `display` handles that and we are working to understand the content of this method and its parameters.

We found that the internal table of `lvc_t_data` type handles horizontal and/or vertical merging of cells (one row of this internal table for each cell), but I struggle to understand how to code cell styling, for example, if I want to wipe just the bottom border or left border. What is the style of different colors, different bolding styles, underlines...?

We found that apart from this variable there is `lvc_t_info` typed parameter, what is it for?

Thanks

Comment: Is it possible that you already asked about this in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26959274/abap-alv-grid-style-numbering?

Comment: Yes but you wanted that i ask that better, I hope that now you understand more whati mean. You have right i am goign to delete the last post

Comment: It would also be enough to edit the old post properly.

Comment: So i need answer not critic thanks ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I Found the answer. Thanks to everyone:

You have to include the cl_alv_contol and you can give all style that you want, like alv_style_color_background + alv_style_font_bold, and the code is a constant in this include.

```
***INCLUDE <CL_ALV_CONTROL> .
CONSTANTS:
* Style 1
 ALV_STYLE_COLOR_BACKGROUND(4)                  TYPE X VALUE '00000001',
 ALV_STYLE_COLOR_HEADING(4)                     TYPE X VALUE '00000002',
 ALV_STYLE_COLOR_NORMAL(4)                      TYPE X VALUE '00000003',
 ALV_STYLE_COLOR_TOTAL(4)                       TYPE X VALUE '00000004',
 ALV_STYLE_COLOR_KEY(4)                         TYPE X VALUE '00000005',
 ALV_STYLE_COLOR_POSITIVE(4)                    TYPE X VALUE '00000006',
 ALV_STYLE_COLOR_NEGATIVE(4)                    TYPE X VALUE '00000007',
 ALV_STYLE_COLOR_GROUP(4)                       TYPE X VALUE '00000008',
 ALV_STYLE_COLOR_INT_BACKGROUND(4)              TYPE X VALUE '00000009',
 ALV_STYLE_COLOR_INT_HEADING(4)                 TYPE X VALUE '0000000A',
 ALV_STYLE_COLOR_INT_NORMAL(4)                  TYPE X VALUE '0000000B',
 ALV_STYLE_COLOR_INT_TOTAL(4)                   TYPE X VALUE '0000000C',
 ALV_STYLE_COLOR_INT_KEY(4)                     TYPE X VALUE '0000000D',
 ALV_STYLE_COLOR_INT_POSITIVE(4)                TYPE X VALUE '0000000E',
 ALV_STYLE_COLOR_INT_NEGATIVE(4)                TYPE X VALUE '0000000F',
 ALV_STYLE_COLOR_INT_GROUP(4)                   TYPE X VALUE '00000010',
 ALV_STYLE_COLOR_INV_BACKGROUND(4)              TYPE X VALUE '00000011',
 ALV_STYLE_COLOR_INV_HEADING(4)                 TYPE X VALUE '00000012',
 ALV_STYLE_COLOR_INV_NORMAL(4)                  TYPE X VALUE '00000013',
 ALV_STYLE_COLOR_INV_TOTAL(4)                   TYPE X VALUE '00000014',
 ALV_STYLE_COLOR_INV_KEY(4)                     TYPE X VALUE '00000015',
 ALV_STYLE_COLOR_INV_POSITIVE(4)                TYPE X VALUE '00000016',
 ALV_STYLE_COLOR_INV_NEGATIVE(4)                TYPE X VALUE '00000017',
 ALV_STYLE_COLOR_INV_GROUP(4)                   TYPE X VALUE '00000018',

 ALV_STYLE_FONT_BOLD(4)                         TYPE X VALUE '00000020',
 ALV_STYLE_FONT_BOLD_NO(4)                      TYPE X VALUE '00000040',

 ALV_STYLE_FONT_ITALIC(4)                       TYPE X VALUE '00000080',
 ALV_STYLE_FONT_ITALIC_NO(4)                    TYPE X VALUE '00000100',

 ALV_STYLE_FONT_UNDERLINED(4)                   TYPE X VALUE '00000200',
 ALV_STYLE_FONT_UNDERLINED_NO(4)                TYPE X VALUE '00000400',

 ALV_STYLE_ALIGN_LEFT_TOP(4)                    TYPE X VALUE '00000800',
 ALV_STYLE_ALIGN_CENTER_TOP(4)                  TYPE X VALUE '00001000',
 ALV_STYLE_ALIGN_RIGHT_TOP(4)                   TYPE X VALUE '00001800',
 ALV_STYLE_ALIGN_LEFT_CENTER(4)                 TYPE X VALUE '00002000',
 ALV_STYLE_ALIGN_CENTER_CENTER(4)               TYPE X VALUE '00002800',
 ALV_STYLE_ALIGN_RIGHT_CENTER(4)                TYPE X VALUE '00003000',
 ALV_STYLE_ALIGN_LEFT_BOTTOM(4)                 TYPE X VALUE '00003800',
 ALV_STYLE_ALIGN_CENTER_BOTTOM(4)               TYPE X VALUE '00004000',
 ALV_STYLE_ALIGN_RIGHT_BOTTOM(4)                TYPE X VALUE '00004800',

 ALV_STYLE_FONT_SYMBOL(4)                       TYPE X VALUE '00008000',
 ALV_STYLE_FONT_SYMBOL_NO(4)                    TYPE X VALUE '00010000',

 ALV_STYLE_CHECKBOX_NOT_CHECKED(4)              TYPE X VALUE '00020000',
 ALV_STYLE_CHECKBOX_CHECKED(4)                  TYPE X VALUE '00040000',
 ALV_STYLE_CHECKBOX_NO(4)                       TYPE X VALUE '00060000',

 ALV_STYLE_ENABLED(4)                           TYPE X VALUE '00080000',
 ALV_STYLE_DISABLED(4)                          TYPE X VALUE '00100000',

 ALV_STYLE_SINGLE_CLK_EVENT(4)                  TYPE X VALUE '00200000',
 ALV_STYLE_SINGLE_CLK_EVENT_NO(4)               TYPE X VALUE '00400000',

 ALV_STYLE_RADIO_NOT_CHECKED(4)                 TYPE X VALUE '00800000',
 ALV_STYLE_RADIO_CHECKED(4)                     TYPE X VALUE '01000000',
 ALV_STYLE_RADIO_NO(4)                          TYPE X VALUE '01800000',

 ALV_STYLE_F4(4)                                TYPE X VALUE '02000000',
 ALV_STYLE_F4_NO(4)                             TYPE X VALUE '04000000',

 ALV_STYLE_IMAGE(4)                             TYPE X VALUE '08000000',

 ALV_STYLE_NO_DELETE_ROW(4)                     TYPE X VALUE '10000000',

 ALV_STYLE_BUTTON(4)                            TYPE X VALUE '20000000',
 ALV_STYLE_BUTTON_NO(4)                         TYPE X VALUE '40000000',


* Style 2
 ALV_STYLE2_NO_BORDER_LEFT(4)                   TYPE X VALUE '00010000',
 ALV_STYLE2_NO_BORDER_RIGHT(4)                  TYPE X VALUE '00020000',
 ALV_STYLE2_NO_BORDER_TOP(4)                    TYPE X VALUE '00040000',
 ALV_STYLE2_NO_BORDER_BOTTOM(4)                 TYPE X VALUE '00080000',

* Style 3 ( WEBSTYLES ).


* Style 4
 ALV_STYLE4_ZEBRA_ROW(4)                        TYPE X VALUE '00000001',
 ALV_STYLE4_STOP_MERGE(4)                       TYPE X VALUE '00000002',

 ALV_STYLE4_LINK(4)                             TYPE X VALUE '00000004',
 ALV_STYLE4_LINK_NO(4)                          TYPE X VALUE '00000008',


* Column Styles
ALV_COL_STYLE_SORT_UP(4)                        TYPE X VALUE '00000001',
ALV_COL_STYLE_SORT_DOWN(4)                      TYPE X VALUE '00000002',
ALV_COL_STYLE_FILTER(4)                         TYPE X VALUE '00000004',
ALV_COL_STYLE_TOTAL(4)                          TYPE X VALUE '00000008',
ALV_COL_STYLE_SUBTOTAL(4)                       TYPE X VALUE '00000010',
ALV_COL_STYLE_CHARACTERISTIC(4)                 TYPE X VALUE '00000020',
ALV_COL_STYLE_KEYFIGURE(4)                      TYPE X VALUE '00000040',
ALV_COL_STYLE_KEY(4)                            TYPE X VALUE '00000080',
ALV_COL_STYLE_EXCEPTION(4)                      TYPE X VALUE '00000100',
ALV_COL_STYLE_SIGNED_KEYFIGURE(4)               TYPE X VALUE '00000200',
ALV_COL_STYLE_MERGE(4)                          TYPE X VALUE '00000400',
ALV_COL_STYLE_FIXED(4)                          TYPE X VALUE '00000800',
ALV_COL_STYLE_AUTO_VALUE(4)                     TYPE X VALUE '00001000',
ALV_COL_STYLE_NO_DISP(4)                        TYPE X VALUE '00002000',
ALV_COL_STYLE_HASREF(4)                         TYPE X VALUE '00004000',
ALV_COL_STYLE_AVERAGE(4)                        TYPE X VALUE '00008000',
ALV_COL_STYLE_MIN(4)                            TYPE X VALUE '00010000',
ALV_COL_STYLE_MAX(4)                            TYPE X VALUE '00020000'.
```

Comment: Hi How did you achieve this , please put some example code , i too need to 
 do the same